What’s the difference between Hyper Light Drifter and Hyper Light Drifter: Special Edition?
Hyper Light Drifter is sold as both a base game and as a "Special Edition" for some consoles.
But what's the difference between Hyper Light Drifter and its Special Edition?

I’d be interested to know why this was downvoted. I’ve seen similar questions that were received well enough.

I don't know, but possibly because the body to the question was only a repetition of the titular question, and provides no additional context. Or because someone thought that, as the downvote button mouseover popup says, your question did "not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful." How this type of question gets voted is indeed very erratic.

The Special Edition adds some new gameplay content and performance improvements, and was released on specific mobile platforms.
From the Wikipedia article on Hyper Light Drifter:

A Special Edition port of the game, featuring additional content, was released by Abylight Studios for the Nintendo Switch in September 2018, for iOS devices in July 2019 and for Android devices in June 2024.

From the Hyper Light Drifter website:

Hyper Light Drifter Special Edition runs at 60 FPS on Switch and iPhone/iPad, and 120 FPS on iPad Pro (with ProMotion enabled), and includes new exclusive content as well as all the previously released: remastered for a perfectly immersive gaming experience to play anywhere.
Key Features

Exclusive Nintendo Switch™ and iOS content:
Find secrets with the help of the new outfit.
Complete the Tower Climb challenge.
Freeze your enemies with the Crystal Shot.
Master the deadly Blade Caster.


A little more info from this Reddit page:

New content info: rewards for completing the new Tower Climb challenge

Tower Climb: a new are[a] accessed in town (6 key door), Archer v2 boss fight at the end.
A new light blue outfit, which makes it easier to find secrets (your drone seems to display an ! sign whenever you get close to one)
Crystal Shot (new weapon): Freeze your enemies into an ice block (seems to have a duration).
Blade Caster (new weapon): Throw your sword for (at least) 2HP damage, dealing 1HP damage on return.


